# Why does $dx\wedge dy$ give the area of the projection of a parallelogram onto the $xy$ plane?

Tags: geometry, intuition, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

[This article](https://simplermath.wordpress.com/2020/02/13/understanding-differential-forms/) on differential forms says that

*"$dx \wedge dy$, $dz \wedge dx$, and $dy \wedge dz$ are just $2$-forms that eat parallelograms and spit out the areas of their projections onto the $xy$, $zx$, and $yz$ planes respectively."*

**Why is that the case?** As an example, why does $dx\wedge dy$ give the area of the projection of a parallelogram onto the $xy$ plane?

Comment: The unsatisfying answer is that this is the definition (and this is what the notes you linked claim). The more satisfying answer requires knowing what wedge products and differential forms are. Work on just $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\{x,y\}$ be a basis. Let $v = ax + by$ and $w = cx + dy$. If you know what a wedge product is, calculate $v \wedge w$; you should get something like $(ad - bc) x \wedge y$. Now $dx \wedge dy$ is the map dual to $x \wedge y$, so you apply it and you get the determinant of the matrix with column vectors $v$ and $w$. This is the signed area of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on User$203940$'s comment, we have

$$dx\wedge dy \ (v^1,v^2) := \sum_{\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_2} \text{sgn}(\sigma) dx\otimes dy \ (v^{\sigma(1)},v^{\sigma(2)}) = \sum_{\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_2} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \ v_x^{\sigma(1)}v_y^{\sigma(2)}$$

which is Leibniz' formula for determinant of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
v_x^1 & v_x^2\\
v_y^1 & v_y^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
i.e. the (signed) area of the projection of the paralellogram spanned by $v^1,v^2$ onto the $xy$ plane.